# No obtengo resultados al hacer BETWEEN en una consulta C#

Tags: c#, sql, base-de-datos, date

Tengo una base de datos en ACCESS, y tengo una tabla dónde uno de los campos es fecha, quisiera traer los datos que están entre dos fechas, por ejemplo entre 01/01/2019 y 02/03/2019.

```
DateTime fecha1 = DateTime.Parse(bunifuDatepicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
DateTime fecha2 = DateTime.Parse(bunifuDatepicker2.Value.ToShortDateString());

   using (OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
   {
     OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Fecha_Compra FROM Compras_Realizadas WHERE Fecha_Compra BETWEEN " + fecha1+ " AND " + fecha2, cnn);
     cnn.Open();

     var reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
     while (reader.Read())
     {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetDateTime(0).ToShortDateString());

     }
    }
```

Pero no obtengo ningun resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que utilices parámetros en la consulta:

```
using (OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
{
     OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Fecha_Compra FROM Compras_Realizadas WHERE Fecha_Compra BETWEEN @fecha1 AND @fecha2", cnn);
     Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("fecha1", bunifuDatepicker1.Value);
     Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("fecha2", bunifuDatepicker2.Value);
     cnn.Open();

     var reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
     ....
}
```